# Why did I got Email Verification - Meta Stack Overflow Newsletter in my mail?

Tags: support, email, newsletter

I'm here for a quite long time, and I can't remember subscribing to any newsletter. No mail-related actions recently, so I don't see what would trigger it.

Mail appears to be from *do-not-reply@stackexchange.com*. How do I know it's genuine? I don't like clicking on links I didn't expect.

Comment: And yes, I had my address visible. Maybe it was a mistake, but so far (until now?) it was never abused.

Comment: You can check the email headers to see if it's genuine, I believe.

Comment: @Stijn it arrived to Gmail - any hint what would I need to look for? And, if possible to tell, how should I do it?

Comment: Sounds like someone just typed your email [into the textbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zDZIH.png), either innocent prank or abuse nobody can really tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, that would explain it.

Comment: @Molot when viewing a mail, at the right side there's a 'Reply' button. Next to it there's a dropdown arrow, click on it and choose 'show original' (or something similar). This will give you the raw email. I don't know the details of determining if an email is authentic though.

Comment: @Stijn `Received: from mx-out.stackexchange.com (mx-out.stackexchange.com. [198.252.206.125])` - looks good. So it probably was just innocent prank or some glitch.